# Getting rid of extra blank lines when writing to file in Python

Tags: python

I am using spaCy to tag named entities in a list of lines. My current code is:

```
from spacy.en import English
parser = English()

for item in datalist:
    #parse the item (sentence)
    parsed = parser(unicode(item))
# tag the lines
    ents = list(parsed.ents)
# write to outfile      
    for entity in ents:
        outfile.write(str(itemnumber) + '\t' + ' '.join(t.orth_ for t in entity) + '\n')
```

The spaCy stuff works fine, but somehow, an extra blank line is added to the outfile in some cases, as below:

```
...
165 it
165 it
165 it greater andre
166 6 12 14 

166 solidarity paristoferguson
167 77
167 shooting deaths
167 cops
167 circumstances
...
```

Such blank lines are added sometimes, but not always, when the thing before the line break is a number.

I tried writing the tagged line to a string, then doing re.sub('\n\n', '\n', string) but the problem persists.

Edit: Adding .strip() to the parser solved it:

```
parsed = parser(unicode(item))
```

Comment: I have no idea what spacy does, but try using `parser(unicode(item).strip())`

Comment: What does the datalist look like? Looks like there are newlines. strip them off with `.strip()`

Comment: Append the suggested `.strip()` to `t.orth_` in the last line of your code.

Comment: there can be some newline while using `for` loop. So use `item.rstrip()` or `entity.rstrip()`.

Comment: Thanks! The .strip() solved it!